# Editing the App Service Editor to adjust the Threshold of my Azure Service Bot

Tags: c#, visual-studio, chatbot, azure-bot-service, threshold

Please I need help adjusting the score threshold to change it from defaulthreshold.

I tried doing this on QnAMakerBasDialog.cs file but I am not sure if I did it correctly or if that is the correct file to be editing because changes I made dont seem to be working.

The exact location on the QnAMakerBasDialog.cs file where I made some changes looks like this

```
            ScoreThreshold = DefaultThreshold,
            Top = DefaultTopN,
            QnAId = 0,
            RankerType = "Default",
            IsTest = false
```

Please I need help with adjusting the threshold for my azure bot (developed with the aid QnA Maker). I would like something like a Threshold of 50.

Answer (score 2):

The threshold is set in the QnAMaker options of your dialog:

```
qnaOptions.ScoreThreshold = 0.3F;
var response = await _services.QnAServices[QnAMakerKey].GetAnswersAsync(turnContext, qnaOptions);
```

The '0.3F' means the response will return any that meet the 30% or above  threshold. So if you're looking for 50% or higher,  change it to '0.5F'

[Confidence Scores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/confidence-score)

[QnAMaker options in bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/metadata-generateanswer-usage)